# Updating DataGrid causes GUI to hang?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.0

So I bind a `DataGrid` to an `ICollectionView`.  I set the virtualization to True.

```
<DataGrid
EnableColumnVirtualization="True"                    EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
IsReadOnly="True"
ItemsSource="{Binding ImportRecords, IsAsync=True}"
Name="ImportRecordsView">
```

I create a task via TPL to populate an ObservableCollection (presumably not on the GUI thread).

```
    Task<ObservableCollection<myClass>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(

        () =>
    {
        var records = new ObservableCollection<myClass>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                    {
                        records.Add(new myClass());
                    }
        return records;

    });
```

I use a continue with that will resume on the GUI thread, and takes the result into a view.  I even use the DeferRefresh() method.

```
        task.ContinueWith( (e) => {
            using (ImportRecordsView.Items.DeferRefresh())
            {
                CollectionViewSource cv = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = e.Result };
                ImportRecords = cv.View;

            }
        }, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Even after all that, there's a second or two where you can't interact with the window (appears like GUI is blocking) until the `DataGrid` fully refreshes.  Is there anything else I can do, or is this just expected behavior?

Comment: Try ListView GridView

Comment: Try to update your DataGrid without task.ContinueWith() as PropertyChanged is dispatched to the UI thread automatically by WPF. Maybe here delaying is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the GUI thread blocks and the application freezes, I would recommend refactoring to use async/await.

Essentially, you can push the heavy lifting onto a background thread using something like  `var result = await Task.Run (() => { return MySlowMethod();});`.

`result` is a `List<T>`, and `MySlowMethod` is some slow method, like a slow database call, which returns something which can be copied into an `ICollectionView`.

The `await` releases control back to the GUI thread, so nothing freezes, and the `Task.Run` executes the heavy lifting on a background thread.

I have used this technique hundreds of times, and it always results in a fast, smooth, responsive app.

For more info, google something like `async await wpf Task.Run`.